# Why is my TextBlock not wrapping?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, word-wrap

I have read nearly every thread about text wrapping on the internet (ok not really) but haven't been able to come up with a solution as to why my `TextBlock` won't wrap. Here is the entire XAML inside of my window:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Errors}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Error}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}"
                               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

What I am getting is a TextBlock that extends way outside of my window. I have tried using other `DataTemplate`s such as `Grid`s but have had no luck. The only solution that has worked was to put a static width on the `TextBlock`, but I would rather not do this. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @StefanDenchev I don't want a static width. I tried using a grid column with a width of star but had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`

```
<ListView .... ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try removing the `DockPanel` inside your `ItemTemplate`?

```
<DockPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Errors}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Error}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}"
                               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: This did not work alone, I also had to disable the horizontal scroll bar on the list view.